# Is $\mathrm{DTISP}(n^a,n^b) \subseteq \mathrm{DSPACE}(n^{b/2})$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, space-time-tradeoff

The title question arose in the course of discussing a [question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290312/can-more-polynomial-time-compensate-for-less-polynomial-memory).  Obviously, from the space hierarchy theorem we know that not only is it false that $\mathrm{DSPACE}(n^b) \subseteq \mathrm{DSPACE}(n^{b/2})$, but there is a proper inclusion *in the other direction*.  But once we limit the time budget of the left-hand side to $n^a$, I'm no longer sure what we can say.

If the question can't be answered unconditionally, then can we answer it conditional on some standard hypothesis or relative to some oracle?

Comment: The answer is presumably no in general, but that implies $\mathbf{L} \neq \mathbf{P}$, so an unconditional proof would be very challenging.

Comment: On the other hand, the answer is trivially yes when $a <= b/2$.

Comment: @WilliamHoza : How do you deduce $\mathbf{L} \ne \mathbf{P}$?

Comment: Assume, say, $\mathbf{DTISP}(n^{10}, n^4) \not \subseteq \mathbf{DSPACE}(n^2)$. Then there is some language $A$ that can be decided in time $O(n^{10})$ (so $A \in \mathbf{P}$) but that cannot be decided in space $O(n^2)$ (so $A \not \in \mathbf{L}$).